# Update Cell Based on Data entered to another cell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am using a `DataGridView` and I am attempting to auto populate a value into a cell based on what a user enters into the previous cell. There will be a query to the DB to capture the appropriate value to be autofilled.

Example:

User enters "1234" into Cell 1 -- Automatically, "5678" is entered into Cell 2.

How can I accomplish this?

I tried something like this and it did not work.

```
Dim X As String
X = dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString
If X = "1234" Then
    dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = "5678"
End If
```

Comment: Where is that code located?  We have no context.  Also, what does `it did not work` mean?

Comment: I had to put the code in a timer because I could not find the correct event that captures a cell being edited on every keystroke. "It did not work" means that the code above did not work. I tried pressing 1234 into cell 1 and nothing happened. The timer is enabled and on a 100 interval. Theoretically, this should have worked, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataGridView CellValueChanged Accomplishes this:

```
Private Sub CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
    Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged

    ' Update the balance column whenever the values of any cell changes.
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 and e.ColumnIndex == 1 And Not dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value Is Nothing AndAlso dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value.ToString() == "1234" Then

        dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value == "5678"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: added a null check

Comment: Thank you. I had tried using this event in the past but I don't think I was correctly calling the method that checks the cell's contents.